# Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'ChildNode' when accessing nextSibling's property

Tags: typescript, dom

[playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYewxgrgtgpgdgFwHQEcIwE4E8DKMA2MYCIGAgvvgBQDkAhjQJRIBmpAonWABZUCWCGFAAEAXgB8wgN4BYAFDDhYEHADOIQknwgA5v0FQkcGAA8EOPgCN8fODoD8SBHR0A5OrEYBueQF9G8vIA9ABUwvIAPKoADnRw4gCMEUExceLygmbCcCDAMJGp8QBMyYXpclFgGHzRCOWgkLCIqOjYeITEpLSFTEam5lY2dl7CQUHCAMSZCPIN0PDIaJi4BEQkGN2xcL3GZhbWtjp9e4OHI2PCUVviJWWRKVU1dfLCIUGBcvJAA)

code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.nextSibling?.tagName);
})

/* 
<span>1</span>
text node
<span>2</span>
<script>
document.querySelector('span').nextSibling; // #text
document.querySelector('span').nextSibling.nextSibling; // <span>2<span>
</script>
 */
```

I'm not using `nextElementSibling` here because I want to iterate text node, too

Comment: not sure what you want. If you want to use tagName. you can cast the `ChildNode` to  `HTMLElement`  - `(item.nextSibling as HTMLElement)?.tagName`

Comment: @MicFung my point is, nextSibling can be a text node ( no tagName prop ) or an element node ( has tagName prop ), but ChildNode just limit its access to tagName prop

Comment: so by casting the nextSibling as HTMLElement like the comment above - `(item.nextSibling as HTMLElement)?.tagName`, it should be able to recognise tagName as property

Comment: @MicFung yeah, but probably a more appropriate assertion would be to `Element` since the `tagName` is defined on that interface :) Other than that, yeah, nothing but an assertion will do.

Answer (score 0):

The comments under your question correctly note that `ChildNode` can be something other than an HTML element, so that's why a property like `tagName` doesn't work by default.

The comments suggest casting to HTMLElement, but it's better to use `instanceof`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(item => {
  if (item.nextSibling instanceof HTMLElement) {
    console.log(item.nextSibling?.tagName);
  }
})
```

This is type-safe, and it leaves the door open to work with text nodes if you want.

Here's another way to do it, though I think it's less clean:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(item => {
  const nextSibling = item.nextSibling;
  if (nextSibling && "tagName" in nextSibling) {
    console.log(nextSibling.tagName);
  }
})
```

If you wanted to filter out everything except for elements, you could use a type guard:

```js
function isHTMLElement(node: Node): node is HTMLElement {
  return node instanceof HTMLElement;
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).filter(isHTMLElement).forEach(item => console.log(item.tagName))
```